# Unable to print the files with special characters while using python

Tags: python

I developed a web crawler to extract all the source codes in a wiki link. The program terminates after writing a few files.

```
 def fetch_code(link_list):
    for href in link_list:
        response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.wikipedia.org/"+href)
        content = response.read()
        page = open("%s.html" % href, 'w')
        page.write(content.replace("[\/:?*<>|]", " "))
        page.close()
```

`link_list` is an array, which has the extracted links from the seed page.

The error I get after executing is

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'M/s.html'
```

Comment: Is the problem really the special characters or is it just that you are trying to read the file name without prepending the full path?

Comment: You are trying to open a file with slash in its name. It means that you are trying to open a file with the name `s.html` in the directory `M`. `open` creates a file if it does not exist, however it does not create a directory. You have to create a directory or substitute slashes with some other symbol e.g. underscore, dash etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot create a file with '/' in its name.

you could escape the filename as M%2Fs.html

/ is %2F

in python2, you could simply use urllib to escape the filename, example:

```
import urllib

filePath = urllib.quote_plus('M/s.html')

print(filePath)
```

on the other hand, you could also save http response to hierarchy, for example, M/s.html means s.html file under directory named 'M'.